# Jinja Get Data From Array and Spaces not showing up?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
@app.route('/')
def explorer():
    
    output = ls()
    
    return render_template('home.html',len = len(output), ls = output, folder_name = os.path.basename(os.getcwd()))
```

here the output is :
['a.out', 'deneme bosluk', 'script.py', 'silme_deneme (copy)', 'Stack.cpp', 'stack.py', 'templates', 'test.py']
deneme bosluk is folder name

```
{%for i in range(0, len)-%}
            
    <input name = {{ls[i]}} type="submit" value={{ls[i]}}>
    <input for = {{ls[i]}} name = {{ls[i]}}_rm type="submit" value=rm>
    <br>
            
{%endfor%}
```

here is my html code.
in here its not showing up spaces in folder name.
deneme bosluk is turned to deneme.[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Your variable names should not be a keyword in the programming language you're using. This means you shouldn't use `len` as a variable name.
2. Try using `{{{` i.e. {{{ls[i]}}}

Comment: <input name = {{{ls[i]}}} type="submit" value={{{ls[i]}}}>

    jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

Comment: its not worked :(